# Was ist ein Wort für eine Gruppe oder jemanden, von der oder dem man sagen würde, dass sie keine Chance in etwas haben?

Tags: phrase, phrase-request

Beispiele 1:

1. Greuther Fürth ist deutlich Letzter auf der Tabelle, sie sind wahre ________
2. *Acht Leichtathleten stehen auf der 100-Meter-Linie...* Markus und Lucas kommentieren die Leichtathleten, und Markus sagt zu Lucas: "Lucas, siehst du diesen _______  in der achten Linie?! Ich gebe dir 100€, wenn er nicht Letzter ist.."
3. Jemand der so aussieht, dass er Letzter oder sehr schlecht in etwas sein wird / ist.

Beispiele 2:

1. Jungs, ich bin die ganze Zeit Erster.. Es muss sein, dass ich mit _______ spiele...
2. *Zwei Leute spielen Schach und ein Spieler macht einen katastrophalen Zug.* Jemand kommentiert: "Oh mein Gott, dass is ein Zug von einem ________"

- Ich suche nicht Wörter wie Amateur oder Beginner, weil sie Erfahrung in einem Feld beschreiben.
- Das Wort muss nich formal sein, es kann auch ein Slangwort sein.

Comment: Willst du ein Wort, das beschreibt, dass jemand einfach schlecht ist? Oder dass er keine Aussicht auf Erfolg hat?

Comment: Mann kann an im sehen dass er keine Aussicht auf Efolg hat!

Comment: Ich habe hierzu eine Frage auf [meta](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1668/diese-frage-hat-8-antworten-ist-eine-community-wiki-sinnvoller) gestellt.

Comment: [Hier](https://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/edit/47566) ist 'ne ganz nette Sammlung. Für die Feinheiten der Bedeutungsunterschiede und beim Gebrauch muss man allerdings selbst weiterforschen. Für mich sind _Flasche_, das englische _Loser_ und _Versager_ sehr gängig (komme aus Westdeutschland). Für die Beispiele: _1 Arschkrampen - 2 Blindgänger - 3 Opfer (jugendsprachlich, vielleicht wieder überholt) - 1b mit lauter Losern - 2b blutiger Anfänger_ oder _Noob_.

Answer (score 8):

Ganz einfach *Verlierer*.  Ein Verlierer muss nicht jemand sein, der schon verloren hat, sondern kann auch jemanden bezeichnen, von dem erwartet ist, dass er es (immer) tut -- oder der auch nur so "aussieht".

*Verlierer* selbst kann durchaus auch formell verwendet werden, abgesehen von der Tatsache, dass es sich halt schon um eine eher negative Wertung handelt.  Alternativ geht, in gleicher Bedeutung, das englische Lehnwort *Loser* (gerne auch falsch geschrieben als *Looser*), welches informell gebraucht wird.

Answer (score 5):

Mein Vorschlag:

Lusche (singular) bzw. Luschen (plural).

Weitere Möglichkeiten sind *Flasche* oder *Pfeife*.

Answer (score 3):

Am Allgemeinsten: Verlierer

Beispiele 1:

- Greuther Fürth ist deutlich Letzter auf der Tabelle, sie sind wahre **Absteiger**.

Das hängt aber von einem Wettbewerb ab, bei dem es am Saisonende einen Abstieg gibt. Schon bei der Fußball-WM würde man nicht "Absteiger" sagen.

- "Lucas, siehst du diesen **Versager** in der achten *Spur*? Ich gebe dir 100€, wenn er nicht Letzter *wird*."

Beispiele 2:

- Jungs, ich bin die ganze Zeit Erster.. Es muss sein, dass ich mit **Pappkameraden** spiele.
- Zwei Leute spielen Schach und ein Spieler macht einen katastrophalen Zug. Jemand kommentiert: "Oh mein Gott, dass ist ein Zug von einem **Anfänger/Blinden/Idioten**".

Auch wenn Du Erfahrungsstatus wie "Anfänger" explizit ausgeschlossen hast - hier wird nicht gesagt, dass jmd. ein Anfänger ist, sondern wie einer spielt.

Comment: Im Schach spricht man auch gerne von einem "Patzer"

Answer (score 3):

- [Nichtskönner](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Nichtskoenner): Also jemand der nichts kann (auch im Plural möglich).
- [Gurkentruppe](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gurkentruppe): Als Gurke wird eine unfähige Person bezeichnet.
- [Niete / Nichtsnutz](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Niete_Nichtsnutz_Los): Jemand, der nichts kann oder nirgendwo nützlich ist
- [Nulpe/Nulpenverein](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nulpe): Ein Dummkopf, Versager oder auch Nichtskönner

Answer (score 2):

Ergänzend zu den anderen Antworten: von Leuten unter 50 wirst du dafür umgangssprachlich auch die englischen Wörter "Noob" (vor allem im Bereich Spiele, auch Schach) oder "Loser" hören.

> Dein Springer ist nicht gedeckt! Du bist so ein Noob.

> Jungs, ich bin die ganze Zeit Erster. Was seid Ihr für Loser?

Comment: Ich hab auch an _Noob_ gedacht, aber das ist ein Synonym für _Anfänger_, und die Frage schließt das gerade aus.

Comment: Jain. Newbi ist Anfänger. Noob ist ein merk- und lernbefreiter Anfänger.

Comment: Gerade im informellen/vulgären gibt es die beliebte Steigerung: Kacknoob

Comment: In meiner ganzen 45-jährigen "Karriere" als Klubschachspieler ist mir das Wort "Noob" praktisch niemals als Bezeichnung für jemanden, der einen schlechten Zug macht, untergekommen - und ich habe zwischen Oberliga und Unterverbandsliga so ziemlich alles gespielt. "Patzer", "Blindes Huhn", in Österreich auch "Wurze" (jemanden, den man ausnehmen kann) hingegen schon oft.

Answer (score 1):

Der voraussichtliche Verlierer in einem Sportwettkampf wird *Außenseiter* oder *Underdog* genannt. Das passt allerdings nicht auf deine Beispiele 2. Für deine Beispiele 2 fallen mir nur Synonyme zu *Anfänger* ein.

Comment: Der voraussichtliche Verlierer wird v.a. Verlierer genannt (Slang).

Comment: @userunknown Ich denke, _Verlierer_ wird man erst nach dem Ausgang des Wettkampfes genannt, _Underdog_ oder _Außenseiter_ ist man schon vor dem Ausgang des Wettkampfes. Es kann vorkommen, dass der Außenseiter gewonnen hat, aber es kommt nicht vor, dass der Verlierer gewonnen hat. Außer, wenn _Verlierer_ als eine Art Charaktereigenschaft verwendet wird, aber dann würde ich zumindest eher _Loser_ sagen.

Answer (score 0):

Naheliegend, aber nicht oft passend ist

> Chancenlose/r

Bei Wahlen (Beispiel: bevorstehende Wahl des deutschen Bundespräsidenten) gibt es einen völlig anderen Begriff:

> Zählkandidat, siehe [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Z%C3%A4hlkandidat).

Answer (score 0):

Mein Vorschlag ist:

> abgehängt

im Sinn von "liegt so weit zurück, dass keine Chance mehr zum Aufholen besteht". Das funktioniert zumindest für die Wettkampf-Szenarien.

Comment: Ich habe die Erklärung etwas erweitert. Für Nichtmuttersprachler reicht es typischerweise nicht, einen Vorschlag ohne irgendwelche Erklärung zu machen.